# How do you do a rolling window regression (with panel data) to get time-variant firm betas in R?

Tags: r, time-series, regression

I have the following dataset of monthly returns of 25 portfolios (the columns) and the market excess returns for corresponding months. I need to get the betas of each of those 25 portfolios but using rolling window estimation. The window size should be 60 months. So in each month, each firm should have a beta that is based on observations in the preceding 60 months. How do I do this?

After estimating the betas, these betas will be used to test whether there is a relationship between high beta and high return.

I'm not even sure where to begin.

I found these codes from
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyfit/vignettes/Rolling_Window_Time_Series_Regression.html

but I don't know how to adjust it accordingly.

```r
mod_frame_rolling <- data %>% 
  regress(Return ~ CMA + HML + `Mkt-RF` + RMW + SMB,
          m("lm", vcov. = "HAC"),
          .cv = "sliding_index", .cv_args = list(lookback = years(5), step = 6, index = "Date"),
          .force_cv = TRUE, .return_slices = TRUE)
```